# How to prevent a failed subprocess during Debian package install terminating the installation immediately

Tags: debian, dpkg

I am creating my own Debian package to install Apache Derby and as part of the install I wish to run a configuration script to set-up some default users. Therefore during the installation I start up the Apache Derby network server and then I test for it's presence by using the 'ping' command of `NetworkServerControl` class.

To allow a short time for the server to start I anticipate the 'ping' command to fail a couple of times so I loop through about 10 times pausing a second between each ping:

```
let retry_count=0
echo "Testing for the Derby network server..."
$(which java) -Dderby.system.home=/srv/apache/derby -cp /usr/lib/apache/derby/derbynet.jar org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl ping -h localhost -p 1527 > /dev/null
until [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; do
    echo "Network server not available."
    let retry_count+=1
    if [[ ${retry_count} -ge 10 ]]; then
        echo "Network server was not available within ${retry_count} seconds. Terminating install." >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    sleep 1
    echo "Testing for the Derby network server..."
    $(which java) -Dderby.system.home=/srv/apache/derby -cp /usr/lib/apache/derby/derbynet.jar org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl ping -h localhost -p 1527 > /dev/null
done
```

However what I have found is that the first ping fails (returning 1) and causes the whole install process to fail:

```
In test_server_up function
Sun Sep 15 12:30:27 BST 2019 : Could not connect to Derby Network Server on host localhost, port 1527: Connection refused (Connection refused)
dpkg: error processing package derby-deb (--install):
    installed derby-deb package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

I have tried assigning the result of the ping command to a variable but I get the same error.

Is there anyway to capture the result of a sub-process and prevent it from terminating the installation?

Comment: I presume this is in, or called from, your post-inst script. Convention is to run shell post-inst scripts with `set -e`, which exits with an error on any **uncaptured** (e.g. "capture" the exit status with `||` or `&&` or `if` etc) non-zero exit code.  Have you tried `set +e` before the ping (or other commands that might return an error code you don't care about) and then returning to `set -e`?

Comment: @cas. Yes. I had blindly included `set -e` in the `postinst` script without fully understanding its meaning. Doing as you suggest resolved the problem. If you provide an answer I will mark as the accepted one. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume this is in, or called from, your post-inst script.

The debian packaging convention is to run shell post-inst etc scripts with `set -e`, which exits with an error on any **uncaptured** non-zero exit code.  You can "capture" the exit status with, e.g.,  `||` or `&&`, or `if`/`elif`, `while`, or `until`.   See `man bash` for details (search for `-e.*Exit`).

e.g.

```
ping_count=0
until ping hostname || [ "$ping_count" -gt 5 ]; do
  sleep 1 # or whatever
  ping_count+=1   # non-posix. won't work with dash.
done
```

Try `set +e` before the ping (or any other commands that might return an error code that you know you **don't** care about) and then return to `set -e` afterwards.

NOTE: I **very strongly recommend against** just getting rid of `set -e` entirely.  If any other program in the post-inst returns with an error code, you (and whoever is installing the package) do want to know about it, and you do want `dpkg` to know that the install failed.